# How to approach studying and proofs in Graph Theory? (question maybe applies to all of Discrete Math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, soft-question, self-learning, learning

I am taking a Graph Theory course and putting a whole lot of effort into it. I learned all the central theorems and can recite the key elements of each of their proofs and replicate the proofs.

However I am terrible when it comes to applying the theorems to some counting/combinatorics problem to get a neat solution. I just cannot ever find the way to fit one of the textbook theorems to the problem. I feel like I have developed no intuition despite putting so much time into the course. This has never happened to me before.

I feel like my studying technique described above is not up to the task. How can I better study for such courses?

Comment: Ok so, in mathematics you need creativity and intuition (combined with theoremes). It is very great that you know everything, but to solve problems, you need an unbeliveable intuition combined with experiecne. If you want more advise from me, please tell me what this course consists of (it may be a bad course!) and tell em at what level you are training. Also, do not worry if you cannot solve hard combi problems. Those are the hardest and trickiest

Comment: @Vlad It is an introductory course but for graduate students. We do all the basics, matchings, connectivity, planarity, colorings, extremal graph theory, random graphs, ramsey theory and some other bits and pieces. It focuses a lot on full complete proofs of all the main results in each section. We only skipped the 4-color-theorem. I feel maybe the problem is that there are no examples on applying the theorems to small problems.

Comment: I am still not sure, but you might simply not be familiar with graph theory. Do not worry, as I said. To proceed, I will give you an "unusual" problem to see how you do and please leave one of the questions you struggle with here in the comments, so I can see what is the type of problems you do. Here is what I think you should try: Given a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, find the minimum number of $K_3$s (triangles) that can be found in this graph.

Comment: @Vlad Given an arbitrary graph $G(n,m)$, applying Turan's theorem you get the max number of edges $m_0$ for which there are no triangles. So then if $m\leq m_0$ the min number of triangles is $0$. Else the min number is $m-m_0$. Is this correct?

Comment: That is not true. Try to use more intuition and not formulas. That is what I wil focus on. I will write an answer tomorrow with the solution and some more recommandations for some books,

Comment: @Vlad My thinking is as follows. A tree ($m=n-1$) has no triangles and a complete graph $m=(n(n-1)/2)$ has $n!/(n-(n-3))!$ triangles for $n>3$. So then I thought what is the maximum number of edges possibles without triangles. That's Turan's theorem which in this case says a bipartite graph is the edge extremal graph without $K_3$ and a bipartite graph contains no odd cycles so this is true. So we know the bound $m_0$ for which the minimum possible number of triangles is $0$. Then if you add an edge there is at least one triangle so for $m>m_0$ there are at least $m-m_0$ triangles.